# Google Wallet Problem

Tags: google, google-wallet

I found out today my cc was under my friends google wallet instead of mine. I was wondering if I delete it from his wallet; will I be able to add it under mine and be capable of using it. I ask because when I go to remove it, it says "This card will no longer be available to use online or on your device", what exactly does that mean if anyone can tell me.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the credit card to your Google Wallet account while leaving it in your friend's account. (My wife and I have each others card under both of our accounts.)

As for the "no longer available" message; that refers to their account only.

Answer (score 1):

It means it won't be able to be used with that Wallet account anymore. You can still add the card to your Wallet account.